# I don't understand why this script doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging

- This script hides the parent block
- if it doesn't have the src of the image loaded.
- Works in all browsers except Firefox

**Is this a Firefox bug or a script issue? If the problem is in the script, how can I make it work in Firefox?**

**P.S**. This error is not visible on this site. Try creating an **index.html** file locally(without using the internet) on your PC and paste this code there, then view the result in Firefox.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block > .Child_Img');

images.forEach(function(e) {
  e.onerror = function() {
    e.closest('.Parent_block').style.display = 'none';
  };
});
```

```css
.Parent_block {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">1</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">2</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: If you suspect Firefox issue, then check chome, i.e. Also do you have tag <!DOCTYPE html>